# Setting display none of an asp panel in client side is re-showing it on any linkButtonclick

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, vb.net, visibility

I am facing a weird issue with visibility of an asp-panel. I have a small form which contains a button inside a panel that makes a div visible.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display: none">
 <span onclick="CloseMyDiv();" id="closeSpan" class="close">×</span>
    <!-- Modal content --> 
</div>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlHasPriorApproval" runat="server" Style="display: none">
   <input onclick="ShowModal();" type="button" value="Extract" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Below are the javascript functions:

```
function ShowModal() {
    $('#myModal').show();
 }

 function CloseMyDiv() {
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'); // this is my div
            var pnlHasPriorApproval = document.getElementById('<%=  pnlHasPriorApproval.ClientID %>');  // this is my pannel
pnlHasPriorApproval.style.display = "none"; // hiding pannel
modal.style.display = "none"; // hiding div
}
```

The process is: whenever I click on this button the div is shown, and whenever I click on close, both div and panel should be hidden ... This is working perfectly. BUT: I have another button whenever I click on it the panel is shown again while it should stay hidden.

This button is handled by a function in server side:

```
Protected Sub lnkBtnphyCode_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkBtnphyCode.Click
....
End Sub
```

I am sure that there is nothing in the server side that is changing the visibility of my panel in this function neither in load page event. Anyway I have implemented my panel inside a div with a new ID "testDiv" to make sure that it is not used anywhere else, and I have done the same process(process is to hide this div onclick) with it and it still appears whenever I click on lnkBtnphyCode.

Solutions tried:

1. I have tried the same process by setting visibility:hidden instead of using display ... but I had the same issue
2. I have added `Dim v = Me.pnlHasPriorApproval.Visible` in my lnkBtnphyCode_Click method, v is returning true which is weird because I have already make it hidden as you can see in the beginning.
3. The only way to make it always hidden and to not appear ON CLICK is to change the visibility in server side which I can't understand why it is not always hidden from javascript(client).

My Question is: How can I make it always hidden from Javascript?

Comment: It is not a weird issue. The server does not know you changed the visibility, so whenerver the page is (re)loaded it will display the Panel. Either use server-side `Visible`, store the state in a `asp:HiddenField` and check on every page load or use an `UpdatePanel`

Comment: And why the other div is still hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript code is executed on client side and ASP.Net is executed on server side. Unless JS code shares the current state information with server, your ASP.Net code won't know the changes done by JS code.

When you click on button, only the form data is submitted to server. So the information that a div and panel are now hidden is not getting passed (which is a normal behavior). If you want to pass it across to server, you will need to explicitly send this info using some hidden form field.

What you can do is:

1. Create a hidden control on the page, say `isPanelVisible`.
2. When you hide the div / panel, set a `true` in the hidden control using JS code.
3. On `Page_Load` in server side code, check the value of this hidden control and accordingly set the visibility of the panel.

That's the typical way of handling such cases.